# Application is not launching from command line full path, because a depend file is not loading

Tags: windows

When i tried to open the abc.exe by double clicking, it is working fine but when i tried to open from command prompt with full path it throw an error due to a dependent file.

Command is - "C:\Program Files\work\project\abc.exe"
and dependent file "abc.txt" also placed at "C:\Program Files\work\project"

when i do the cd C:\Program Files\work\project and then try to open the abc.exe, it is working fine.

At all other systems it is working fine buy at my pc it is giving error.
I checked the registry seeting and path but did not see and difference.

Please suggest me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Please post the error stack.

Comment: An pop error comes which is designed in abc.exe code if the file "abc.txt" is not present at "C:\Program Files\work\project" but this file is present and properly accessible when i open this using cd path.